# Как правильно пишется проектная и рабочая документации или документация?

Tags: окончания

Как правильно пишется проектная и рабочая документации или документация?

Answer (score 2):

Слово *документация* не имеет множественного числа:

*проектная и рабочая документаци**я**.*

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Голосую за этот ответ, потому что не хочу соглашаться с викисловарем, который не против формы множественного числа слова "документация".